# FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW **AND** FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH

Tags: php, filter, sanitize

how can i implement both FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH and FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW .. i have written

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fname", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

will this work?

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should OR them together;

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fname", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

Comment: ok. thank you but i thought the OR was two vertical lines ie ||

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Comment: You are correct, I should have written bitwise or, which is only one.